# Firebase References - Local Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

When I create a firebase reference and take a snapshot of that reference while authenticated through firebase authentication then I log out, that data remains.

Requirements:

1. Page cannot be reloaded or force reloaded after logout
2. Cannot Clear Firebase Session or all data will need to be reloaded
3. Must clear only the data that was accessable to the user and not to the public
4. Must also reload data that is owned or is in the same group as the non-escalated or guest user after the other user has logged out.

I am considering creating objects that wrap my references that will supply a user group and other permissions property as is commonly seen on linux. This will allow me to use the current user object that provides group and user details as a base for deactivating or clearing local data.

Is there a standard way of doing this? 
Am I making more work of this than is needed?

I will be hardcoding the knowledge of what groups have permission on the clientside to be replaced later with metadata provided by firebase. I plan to eventually keep track of all references available to a specific user under the user id as well as keep track of the references available publicly and as well again keep track of references available to specific groups where the highest permissions takes priority.

Step one I am taking is creating a way to manage the references clientside and build in checks for authentication change and then utilizing the user details provided in the current auth apply needed changes with authenitication change kicks off. Is it easier to just initiate another call to the server for that snapshot, will that snapshot change if it is no longer authorized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You control your own app and the prefs based snapshot (or wherever else you save the data) is under your app control as well. Assuming that whatever local storage is protected to your app only (whether natively by Android OS such as private prefs or otherwise), you can simply save the local cache under the user id of the currently authenticated user. So your app can check if the authenticated user matches that user id of the cache and if it does not, then access is denied. In fact, the local cache should be keyed minimally by the logged-in user so you get that kind of check for free (basically the snapshot data won't be found).